# Spork error with bundle exec?

Tags: rubygems, spork

Whenever I run `spork`, I am getting the following error:

```
You have already activated spork 0.9.0.rc8, but your Gemfile requires spork 0.8.5. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

my gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem "rspec"
    gem "rspec-rails"
    gem "factory_girl_rails"
    gem 'spork' 
    gem 'webrat'
    gem 'awesome_print'

    gem 'vcr'
    gem 'fakeweb'
end
```

I have ran `bundle update` and `gem update` and even `gem update --system` but I am still seeing this error. running `bundle exec spork` works, but I want to know why `spork` doesn't and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is already solved (I would assume), but I faced a similar problem the last few days and found the reason for this error. It has to do with the versioning of all needed gems when using bundler. When only "`spork`" is provided then `RubyGems` gets activated and looks for an appropriate version. But this bypasses the specified version from the `Gemfile` that the bundler would use. Only when "`bundle exec spork`" is used, the bundler can look up the version from the `Gemfile`. In your case "`spork`" points to an installed gem with version '`0.9.0`', while "`bundle exec spork`" uses '`0.8.5`'.
There is a flag available ("bundle exec --binstubs") that creates a "`bin`" folder (>= bundler 1.0) and puts all executables specified by the Gemfile into it. Instead of "bundle exec spork" it is valid to write "`bin/spork`".

Search for "Gem Versioning and Bundler: Doing it Right" by **Yehuda Katz**, it explains everything in more detail and helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile you can specify:

```
gem 'spork', :version => 0.8.5
```

Also you might wanna delete newer spork:

```
gem uninstall spork -v=0.9.0.rc8
```