# Spork Error upon bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails, spork

I ran bundle update on my rails app. I'm not getting the following error and can't figure out what i need to change:

59$ spork
Using RSpec, Unknown

Loading Spork.prefork block...

You have already activated spork 1.0.0rc2, but your Gemfile requires spork 1.0.0rc3. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

It runs ok if i run it with bundle exec, but i want to fix the root cause so that I don't have to use bundle exec. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't figure out why the rc2 vs. rc3 issues was present, but in general, after reading a few sites i think bundle exec was the way to go. I ended up using the following setup to get a development and test environment running smoothly for TDD.  As a result, i'm not facing the issue, though I still don't what caused the issue.

http://blog.crowdint.com/2012/03/01/rails-tdd-environment-setup-with-guard-and-foreman.html

Answer (score 0):

Run `gem update spork` and it will update the version of spork installed on your system to the latest version. Right now you've only installed that version of spork in your bundle, which won't be seen when you run the command without `bundle exec`. You may also need to remove the older versions with `gem cleanup spork`

Comment: Thanks. I did both update and cleanup and there doesn't seem to be spork at the system level.  i found the following which talks about the need for bundle exec. I'd still love to understand why it's seing a different version of spork when the update or cleanup command can't find it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218262/spork-error-with-bundle-exec

Comment: Then you should install spork on the system. 'gem install spork`.

Comment: Sorry, i don't get how installing spork at the system level will explain that it's currently seeing two versions of spork already without the system level gem. Am I missing something?